# UIGestureRecognizer not get detecting my UIView completely

Tags: ios, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I create main `UIView`. and then add two UIViews over it.

And attached `UIGestureRecognizer` to mainView. But when I tap on main View, it get detected only half part of mainView.

Does anyone know why this is,

```
-(void)addTapGesture:(UIView*)view
{
    view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *oneFingerTwoTaps = 
    [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(detailInfo:)] autorelease];

    // Set required taps and number of touches
    [oneFingerTwoTaps setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [oneFingerTwoTaps setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    oneFingerTwoTaps.delegate=self; //gesturRecognize delegate
    // Add the gesture to the view
    [view addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerTwoTaps];           
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are using then people can help out

Comment: Main view mean which one view controller view or programatically u added view?

Comment: main view is my custom view... not self.view

Comment: If you used Interface Builder to create the view, can you please provide a screenshot? It may be that some view is overlapping the mainView in which you want the gesture recogniser to work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is some other view Overlapping your mainView layer, or if there is some other Guesture added on your mainView which could be cancelling the tap guesture of you mainView

Comment: I also added PanGesture, but it belonging to another uiView in same IB .Does it effect on mainView tap Action?

Answer (score 0):

Conform your ViewController to `<UIGestureRecoganizerDelegate>`

And then call the delegate method in your viewController.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    NSLog ("Touch View : %@", touch.view);
    NSLog ("GestureRecoganizer View : %@", touch.view); //Check if both views are same
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass: [YourViewClass class]]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Hope it will helps U.. Happy Coding :)